# iron router: render template in named yield from event

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

can I somehow render a template in a specific yield from an event using iron router?

Template:

```
<template name="groupDetails">
    {{#with selectedGroup}}
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        {{> groupNav}}
        {{> yield 'groupOption'}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Event action:

```
Template.groupNav.events({
  'click .groupStatisticsNavLink': function () {
    layout.render('stats', { to: 'groupOption' });
  }
});
```

I want to render a template called "stats" in a yield named "groupOption" from pressing a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside template helpers and events, you can just use a reference to Iron.controller(), which returns the current RouteController.

```
var controller = Iron.controller();
// you now have access to all controller properties and methods
```

so your event would look like

```
Template.groupNav.events({
  'click .groupStatisticsNavLink': function () {
    var controller = Iron.controller();
    controller.render('stats', { to: 'groupOption' });
  }
});
```